# How to add accessibility focus on an Edit Text drawable right (Talkback)

Tags: android, android-edittext, accessibility, android-drawable, talkback

I have an `editText` that contains a `drawableRight` property. This `editText` is a search field, and the `drawableRight` is an "x" icon for clearing the text from the search field. When using `Talkback` (screen reader), I can't select the drawableRight to trigger my `onTouch()` event as it thinks I'm trying to tap on the editText as a whole.

I've tried to use `.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)` on my `editText drawable`, but accessibility functions can only be used on elements that inherit from `View`.

When I try to access the drawable like this `editText.getCompoundDrawables()[4]` it doesn't give me any accessibility options, as it does not inherit from View.
I need to find a way to let people with disabilities be able to tap on the "x" drawable from my edit text to clear the search bar text.

Comment: Kindly add some relevant code so that the issue can be pointed out.

Comment: @AdnanTemur I can't share my code as it's confidential to my company. But it's a simple edit text with a "clear" icon set as a drawableRight. Talkback should be able to allow user to tap on that icon. If you turn on the talkback on your android and try to tap on the drawable on any edit text, it won't allow you.

Comment: Is the icon working on normal touch?

Comment: @AdnanTemur Yes, it works on normal touch. Unfortunately the solution I found (and disliked it), was to remove the drawableRight and simply add an image view on top of the edit text to mimic the functionality of a drawableRight. That way I was able to add `.sendAccessibilityEvent()` to it, as it inherits from View.

Comment: Why didn't you send two accessibilty events for the same view (EditText).

Comment: You might have implemented the onTouch listener for the drawable and editText inside an if statement. So if(it is drawable)drawable's accessibilty event, else {view's accessibilty event}

Comment: Hi, were you able to fix this problem? I am facing something similar.

Comment: @AdnanTemur, the DrawableRight isn't accessible when using the swipe gesture in TalkBack mode. It selects the entire `EditText`. Someone using TalkBack mode generally can't rely on their vision to reliably hit inside the DrawableRight bounds. The DrawableRight needs to be treated as a separate view...